# How to read regular spaced negative integers from input in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

How to read and separate regular spaced negative integers from input() in python 3? I came to this while I was doing this CodeChef.com's problem
https://www.codechef.com/NACA2019/problems/STGAME

I thought of my usual way of using input().split() but that would separate negative signs too separately and it'll make the integers positive which I also don't want.

It would have been easier in C language due to scanf()

```py
strArr = input().split() #My usual way of splitting the string input
list cardsArr
for j in strArr:
    cardsArr.append(int(j)) # usual way to convert the list to integers
#I want to know how to read it.
```

INPUT
1 2 3 4 5
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5

EXPECTED RESULTS
[1,2,3,4,5]
[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]

ACTUAL RESULTS
[1,2,3,4,5]
[-,1,-,2,-,3,-,4,-,5]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, your code has a syntax error (`list cardsArr`), and your "actual results" have invalid syntax (minus sign literals). Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Use `input().split(" ")` to split at every space.

Comment: `str.split()` by default splits on whitespace, so `input().split()` should work for the given input. The question is missing something.

Answer (score -1):

using `filter`

```
a=list(map(int,input().strip().split())) # '1 2 3 4 5 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5'
c=list(filter(lambda x:x>=0,a))
b=list(filter(lambda x:x<0,a))
print(c,b)

# output  [1,2,3,4,5],[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]
```